# Rotate Y-axis categorical label in Seaborn plot?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

To borrow some default code with default libraries (extra helpful that you have to load the data explicitly, instead of having it polluting globals like in R...):

```
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.violinplot(y="day", x="total_bill", data=tips)
```

This produces the following image:

[image]

I want to rotate the day of the week labels 90 degrees such that the baseline for those labels matches the word `day`, also on the Y axis.

I've looked at the answers already here, but they seem primarily to deal with (1) the X axis and (2) the first-order Y-axis label (here, the `day` label) rather than the Y-axis sub-labels (here, the days of the week).

Comment: You can take any answer for xticklabels and replace the x by a y.

Comment: Tried that, `ax.set_yticklabels(rotation=90)` yields an error. Answer below, accepted, also notes and corrects for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most stackoverflow answers would recommend using `ax.set_yticklabels(rotation = 90)`, while this does work, it also requires you to provide the positional parameter `labels` (failing to provide this will give you a `TypeError`). I'd recommend using `plt.yticks(rotation = 90)`. This is how it'd look:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set(style="whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.violinplot(y="day", x="total_bill", data=tips)
plt.yticks(rotation = 90)
plt.show(ax)
```

[image]

Comment: The recommended way would rather be `ax.tick_params(axis="y", rotation=90)`. Which other answers use `set_yticklabels`?